# How do I customize the Launcher in Unity 2D?

Tags: 11.04, menu, unity-2d

I want to add/remove items on the Launcher. I'm using Unity 2D.

Of course I looked it up on Google, and I saw instructions that said when I have an application open, I can right click on it and a menu option will appear to say I can make the icon permanent.

However, when I right click on the icon for an open application, all I see is an option to close the application, nothing else.

Also, right clicking on any of the permanently available default icons does nothing. I want to remove some, for example the software center icon.

How do I customize Launcher in Unity 2D?

Comment: @gd1: I agree entirely. This question was asked during the phase when I was giving it a fair shake, to experiment and see how usable it was. All my experimentation, however, led to the point where I abandonded it and I now use Gnome Classic with Compiz Effects. It's not 100% back to the Gnome 2.2 interface, but it's close enough that I won't abandon Ubuntu yet.

Comment: I am so sorry for this. I'm currently installing Debian from scratch and I think I'll use LXDE.

Comment: @gd1: I tried LXDE, and many others. Gnome Classic, for all its faults is still, IMHO, better than any others.

Comment: I'm fine with LXDE even though I'm not enthusiast. I just can carry on my work, and that's fine enough. With Insanity I become unproductive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To arrange applications on the
   launcher in Unity 2D, press Alt-F2, then type the
   command below and select
   gconf-editor program to open.

   ```
    gconf-editor
   ```
2. Next, scroll down to
   desktop>unity-2d>launcher then
   right-click on favorites and select
   ‘Edit Key’
3. Now you can re-arrange applications
   on the launcher as you like by using
   the Up / Down buttons.

*To quickly add your favorite applications the Unity Launcher, open an application, then right-click on the application icon on the launcher and select ‘Keep in Launcher’*

Comment: The gconf-editor approach did not do anything for me, but oddly enough, after I went there, then the right-click option became available. It seems the workspace switcher can not be removed though.

Comment: @Dave M G unfortunately some icons like the workspace switcher are immutable. You might try logging a bug?

Answer (score 1):

To re-arrange icons in the launcher, click on an icon and wait for one second before you start dragging.

Comment: With Unity 2D you have to hold down the left mouse button for at least 2 second hover the icon of the program you want to move. After that time you can drag anywhere on the launcher.
http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/10/customizing-unity-2d-ubuntu-natty.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also a really good guide here as to how to edit and rearrange your 2d unity which I found really useful.

It is still working with compiz which does still work but means you can add lots more functionality and like many of us Linux users fiddle* (*=break) about with your system until you are happy with it.

Try this :

[Configure Unity 2D to Simulate Unity 3d](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1748671)

All credit to Ubuntu forum user **Entyrion** for this how to

An alternative which is much smaller and easier but less changable is the great little GUI that **Mariano Chavero** created which is available on his blog here but it does not let you edit menu entries but lets you mess with other settings (autohide, dash,composting etc)

[Mariano Chavero's Unity 2d GUI](http://marianochavero.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/a-simple-gui-for-unity-2d-settings-ubuntu-11-04/)